# Show only one div at a time from list of div sequentially after perticular interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Let say I have six divs at my html having same class like

```
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
```

I want to display first div for 3 second and hide other 5 divs. After 3 second, I want to display only second div and want to hide other divs so that this cycle will going through first div to last div and again start from first div.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: have a google for jquery slider / slideshow, there are plenty of plugins out there

Comment: I have applied but it hides all divs.

`setInterval(function () {
jQuery('.post').each(function(index){
      jQuery(index).removeClass("hidden").siblings().addClass("hidden");
});
},3000);`

Comment: When asking questions, please always show what code/libraries you have, even though it does not work. It shows us that you are willing to research the question and try something before asking - presently it looks like you have done nothing at all, even if that is not actually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using a `setInterval` where you display the corresponding block of div within a given interval.

Please refer code and take inputs:

```js
var child = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  $(".post").show().not(".post:nth-child(" + child + ")").hide();
  if (child === 7) {
    child = 1;
  } else {
    child++;
  }
}, 600); // this time period is in ms, use 3000 for 3 secs
```

```css
.post {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">1</div>
<div class="post">2</div>
<div class="post">3</div>
<div class="post">4</div>
<div class="post">5</div>
<div class="post">6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example using `setTimeout` function :

```
 $(".post").hide();
 var index = 0;

 function start() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $(".post").hide();
     $(".post").eq(index).show();
     index++;
     if (index == $(".post").length) {
       index = 0;
     }
     start();
   }, 1000);
 }
 start();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eanhrngn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval for a continuous loop.

```js
var i = 1;
var divs = $(".post");
divs.not(":first").hide();

var length = divs.length
setInterval(function() {

  divs.hide();

  $(".post").eq("" + i + "").show();
  i++;

  if (i == length) {
    i = 0;
  }

}, 3000);

$(".post")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">1</div>
<div class="post">2</div>
<div class="post">3</div>
<div class="post">4</div>
<div class="post">5</div>
<div class="post">6</div>
```